MQTT NodeJS permanent disconnect and reconnect
I'm starting my MQTT client in TypeScript and the connection is successful. However, the connection always ends and reconnects. I didn't changed anything and a few days later I'm getting the following logs in my Docker container. There was no fix even after a docker system prune -af.
const TOPIC_NAME = ['isumis/sub', 'blacklight_collector/blacklight', 'blacklight_collector/trackerdb'];
const mqttURL = 'mqtt://127.0.0.1:1884';

export function subscriber(): Promise<Message> {
    console.log('Subscribe to ' + TOPIC_NAME[0] + '...');
    const client = connect(mqttURL, { clientId: 'blacklight-subscriber' });

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        client.on('error', function (error) {
            console.log('Unable to connect subscriber: ' + error);
            process.exit(1);
        });

        client.on('connect', function () {
            console.log('Is connected: ' + client.connected);
            if (client.connected) {
                console.log('Waiting for messages...');
                client.subscribe(TOPIC_NAME[0], (err) => {
                    if (!err) {
                        console.log('Hello');
                    } else {
                        console.error('Subscription failed: ' + err);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        
        client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
            console.log('Received message on ' + topic + '...');
            const msg = new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(message);
            console.log(msg);
            let obj: Message = JSON.parse(msg);

            resolve(obj);
        });
        
        client.on('close', () => console.log('Client disconnected.'));
    });
}

[...]
1719217885: New connection from 172.18.0.5:41938 on port 1883.
1719217885: Client blacklight-subscriber already connected, closing old connection.
1719217885: New client connected from 172.18.0.5:41938 as blacklight-subscriber (p2, c1, k60).
1719217886: New connection from 172.18.0.1:53374 on port 1883.
1719217886: Client blacklight-subscriber already connected, closing old connection.
1719217886: New client connected from 172.18.0.1:53374 as blacklight-subscriber (p2, c1, k60).
1719217887: New connection from 172.18.0.5:41954 on port 1883.
1719217887: Client blacklight-subscriber already connected, closing old connection.
1719217887: New client connected from 172.18.0.5:41954 as blacklight-subscriber (p2, c1, k60).
1719217888: New connection from 172.18.0.1:53386 on port 1883.
1719217888: Client blacklight-subscriber already connected, closing old connection.
1719217888: New client connected from 172.18.0.1:53386 as blacklight-subscriber (p2, c1, k60).
1719217889: New connection from 172.18.0.5:41962 on port 1883.
1719217889: Client blacklight-subscriber already connected, closing old connection.
1719217889: New client connected from 172.18.0.5:41962 as blacklight-subscriber (p2, c1, k60).
[...]

I figured out that this line Client blacklight-subscriber already connected, closing old connection. could be the problem but I don't know how to fix it.
Using mosquitto_sub -v -t 'isumis/sub' -p 1884 works well (Port 1884 is used for the Docker container to connect via localhost).

It is hard to say as you didn't include the code calling this function... If you call 'subscriber' more than once, this is normal as you create a new connection with the same clientId at every call. I think the usage of the promise here is wrong, the promise is resolved on first message, then the next call will disconnect the previous subscription. You should pass a callback to be called on every message received or write a generator function.

Based on the mosquitto logs there are connections from client blacklight-subscriber coming from two IP's (172.18.0.1 and 172.18.0.5). 172.18.0.1 is probably your host (or something accessing the container via your host) and 172.18.0.5 is the container you are running your python in. You will need to change the client Id that one or other of these systems is using.

@CyrilG. I'm calling the subscriber function only once.

@Brits Yes, changing the client Id helped.
